# ASP.NET Core MVC for error page always returns 404, WHY?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my project (.NET 6.0) I use app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute() to get the status code and redirect to a URL with that. But when I try , it always returns 404 status code. Do I miss something ??

Program.cs

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/{0}");
  app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
  app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/{0}");
  app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
}
```

ErrorController

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult HttpStatusCodeHandler(int statusCode)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            switch (statusCode)
            {
                case 400: ViewBag.ErrorMesage = "400"; break;
                case 401: ViewBag.ErrorMesage = "401"; break;
                case 403: ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "403"; break;
                case 404: ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "404"; break;
                case 500: ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "500"; break;
            }
            return View("ErrorAdmin");
        }
        switch (statusCode)
        {
            case 400: ViewBag.ErrorMesage = "400"; break;
            case 401: ViewBag.ErrorMesage = "401"; break;
            case 403: ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "403"; break;
            case 404: ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "404"; break;
            case 500: ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "500"; break;
        }
        return View("Error");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

If you are not authenticated and want to reach a page, before Error/{0}, it redirects you to Account/Login?ReturnUrl...

and then if this Routing doesn't exists it returns 404 to Error/{0}.

I used this ;

```
       services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
       {
           options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/error/403");
           options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
           options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
           options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720);
           options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
       });
```

So I have a Login method and when the user isn't authenticated, user will be redirected to /login, if is not authorized, will be redirected to /error/403